# Critique this c++ code

Tags: c++

Similar to the code written below exists in production. Could you people review it and tell me if such code works well all the time.

```
class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void process() = 0;
};

class ProductA : public Base
{
    public:
    void process()
    {
        // some implementation.
        doSomething();
    }

    void setSomething(int x)
    {

    }

    virtual void doSomething()
    {
         // doSomething.
    }

};

class ProductANew : public ProductA
{
    public:
        ProductANew() : ProductA() { }
        void doSomething()
        {
           // do Something.
        }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Base* bp = new ProductANew();
    dynamic_cast<ProductA*>(bp)->setSomething(10);
    bp->process();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the definition of `class ProductA` should actually start with `class ProductA : public Base`

Comment: What's your concern - the dynamic cast? Where does that come from / why can't you use a ProductA* not a Base* - are you storing your ProductA in a common array or similar?

Comment: is there a specific question in there, like will this kind of use of dynamic_cast always work etc? For the record, dynamic_cast might give you a null pointer if the RTTI doesn't fit, which you directly dereference without a check. But otoh, if this is really your production code and the cast is done immediately after instantiation like this, you've got nothing to worry about. Oh, and your ProductA doesn't inherit from Base...

Comment: is ProductA inherited from Base?

Comment: Yes.. I just updated the code.

Comment: And now, what is `Product`? It is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I would definitely static_cast here since we are guaranteed to recieve an instance of A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With good design you wouldn't need a `dynamic_cast`. If `process()` can't be called without calling `setSomething()` first they should have been exposed in  the same base class.

Comment: Yes.. that is one of the review comments I was expecting. Thanks.

Comment: A good design for what? Are - just a wild guess - the subclasses of Base going to encapsulate the implementation of algorithms and then these objects are going to be arranged as a network of processes? If so, sharptooth advice of exposing doSomething() on Base interface doesn't look like a good idea to me...

Comment: @miquelramirez, what if setSomething(int x) is made part of Base method and provide a default implementation ? We would not need a dynamic_cast to Product right.

Comment: @miquelramirez, well setSomething(int x) has to be virtual though.

Comment: Perhaps something like:

Base* bp = new ProductANew();
std::map<std::string, int> parameters;
parameters["something"] = 10;
bp->configure(parameters);
bp->process();

Where you have a virtual method, Base::configure( std::map<std::string, int>& ) with default implementation being void - perhaps. Sub-classes can override this method, to check that certain parameters have been specified by the user.

The real problem comes when you might have *any* type as a parameter. One solution  - which I am quite familiar with - could be this one: http://clam-project.org/wiki/Processings_with_configuration

Answer (score 19):

Some problems:

- the base class must have  a virtual destructor
- you never delete the object allocated with new
- you never test the result of dynamic_cast

Answer (score 3):

There's one actual error and a bunch of dangerous/questionable practices:

---

The one error is that you never call `delete` on your `new`ed object, so it leaks.

---

Questionable practices:

1. `Base` doesn't have a virtual destructor, so if you correct the error by calling `delete` or using an `auto_ptr`, you'll invoke undefined behaviour.
2. There's no need to use dynamic allocation here at all.
3. Polymorphic base classes should be uncopyable to prevent object slicing.
4. You're using a `dynamic_cast` where it's not neccessary and without checking the result - why not just declare `bp` as a pointer to `ProductANew` or `ProductNew`?
5. `ProductANew` doesn't need  a constructor  - the  default one  will do  just fine.

A few of these points may be a result of the nature of your example - i.e. you have good reason to use dynamic allocation, but you wanted to keep your example small.

Comment: IIRC, on most platforms an application's heap is automatically released upon termination. As such, omitting `delete` is definitely not recommended, but is not an error per se, and will not necessarily cause a leak.

Comment: I'd still view any object that's hasn't been destroyed by the end of the program as an error - but you're right, on any modern consumer environment it's not an issue unless the object is holding some other resources that the OS can't clean up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you'll find that code which can't even compile is badly designed.

```
Base* bp = new ProductANew();
```

This line can't work because ProductANew isn't inherited from Base in any way, shape or form.

```
$ gcc junk.cc
junk.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
junk.cc:41: error: cannot convert ‘ProductANew*’ to ‘Base*’ in initialization
```

(Just to be clear: junk.cc contains your code cut and pasted.)

---

*Edited to add...*

Latecomers may want to look at the history of the original question before down-voting. ;)

Comment: -1 the 'delete' button can be used to remove spurious answers so that  people's time isn't spent reading them.